# Alter Sass based on local config settings?

Tags: sass

I'm using Sass and Modernizr in my styles eg its checked property:

```
    .checked .class {
        colour: blue;
    }
```

My Sass need to be consumed by another application, however this application doesn't have Modernizr as it doesn't need to support older browsers. So it needs to lose the checked property:

```
    .class {
        colour: blue;
    }
```

Is there a way to write my Sass so that a local config file could dictate weather or not the checked property is used? Something like this pseudo code:

```
    {{ if modernizr }}
    .checked {
    {{ endif }}
        .class {
            colour: blue;
        }
    {{ if modernizr }}
    }
    {{ endif }}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use variable for vendor class name.
In your project you set `$vendor-name`to `.checked`. In other app you set it to empty string.

**App with Modernizr support**

```
$vendor-name: '.checked';

#{$vendor-name} .class {
  color: red;
}
```

Css output:

```
.checked .class {
  color: red;
}
```

**Other app:**

```
$vendor-name: '';

#{$vendor-name} .class {
  color: red;
}
```

Css output:

```
.class {
  color: red;
}
```